# Segmentation fault for sorted linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to insert a node then sort it into a sorted linked list, but I keep getting a segmentation fault. However, I don't really see where I went wrong: `insertNode` is library function, so I don't think the error lies there.
Other questions that I found used the head as a node, but I don't think I did?
I'm new to this topic so I don't understand a lot of what exactly I'm doing, can anyone help?

```
int insertSortedLL(LinkedList *ll, int item) {
    // add your code here
    ListNode *cur = ll->head;
    ListNode *temp;
    int swapped;
    
    insertNode(ll, ll->size, cur->item);
    if (ll == NULL || ll->head == NULL)
        return -1;
    else {
        swapped = 0;
        do {
            if (ll->head > cur->next->item) {  
                int temp = ll->head; 
                ll->head = cur->next->item; 
                cur->next->item = temp;  
                swapped = 1; 
            } else
                cur = cur->next;
        } while (swapped && ll->head != NULL);
        return 0;
    }   
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. And we can't debug incomplete code. Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also show a [mcve], the problem could already be within the creation of the list. Read this: [ask]

Comment: _"`insertNode` is an inbuilt function"_: huh?

Comment: `ll->head > cur->next->item`. That doesn't look right. You haven't shown the the definition of any of the structures. But it looks like `head` is a `ListNode *` wherease `item` is the actual data and not a node pointer. The compiler should give a warning for that.

Comment: Argh, in fact the next three lines all look wrong for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

`if (ll->head > cur->next->item)` in this statement, you cannot compare an adress `head` and  an integer.
The statement should be

```
if (ll->head->item > cur->next->item)
```

Also you cannot assign a pointer to an integer.
This is a wrong statement.

```
int temp = ll->head;
```

If `item` is an integer, you should write

```
int temp = ll->head->item;
```

You should be careful. Also you can use GDB for debugging.